# How to detect the x and y position of a clone?

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm trying to make a marker that puts a number on each clone, so I can assign a life variable to each one, but I haven't been able of doing so. Any ideas?

I tried setting each clone to a different color and using it to set them to a number, but I don't know how to take the position of the clone so I can move the marker with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to first create 1 variable called "Clone ID" (make sure to make it
"for this sprite only" ) and write

[image]

```
[scratchblocks]
when green flag clicked
set [clone ID v] to [1]
[/scratchblocks]

[scratchblocks]
define create clone
create clone of [myself v]
change [clone ID v] by (1)
[/scratchblocks]
```

This may not be obvious, but this code makes it so that each clone you create has a unique Clone ID(this is the reason we made the variable "for this sprite only" ) and now we can write[image]

```
[scratchblocks]
when I start as a clone
forever
replace item (clone ID v) of [x positions] with ((x position))
replace item (clone ID v) of [y positions] with ((y position))
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

Now we have stored each of the clones positions

if you now want to add a live count for each of them you just have to create a lives variable and a lives list and replace the x positions with the lives variable and the list with the lives list  [image]

```
[scratchblocks]
when I start as a clone
forever
replace (clone ID v) of [lives] with ((lives))
end
[/scratchblocks]
```